# Why is this PHP construct not an array, btw What is It if not an Array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having trouble with my arrays.

```
$mini_one = array(
    "in" => "#pp1",
    "ot" => "the-r1",
    "fn" => "the_r1()",
    "js" => "$('the-r1').val($('#pp1').val());",
    "ep" => "not tested"
);

$mini_two = array(
    "in" => "#pp1",
    "ot" => "the-r1",
    "fn" => "the_r1()",
    "js" => "$('the-r1').val($('#pp1').val());",
    "ep" => "not tested"
);
//these are different but i just c/p it to show more than one array 
//inside of $big_array

$big_array = array($mini_one,$mini_two);
```

but when I test the big_array with is_array() it returns false, it also doesn't work in my foreach loop.

I would like to know why it is not an array?, how I can make it into a correct array?, and, as it is now, what type of construct it is considered?

Comment: I am guessing because they have the same element names, the in, ot, fn and such

Comment: Given your sample code, `is_array($big_array)` returns 1. There's something different about your *actual* code, but we can't say what it is without seeing it.

Comment: I am getting true for `is_array($big_array)`: http://codepad.org/daqgQRqH

Comment: how to help if you provide copy/paste samples except the problematic arrays?

Comment: but that shouldn't be effecting the big_array, right? those keys need to be the same for my foreach loop.

Comment: orks for me php 5.3.2 ubuntu 10.04

Comment: `in_array` works with the code you posted. If you don't post the problematic code, we cannot help you because you have no problem we can solve.

Comment: It works fine for me. Added `if(is_array($big_array)) var_export($big_array);` and it outputted as expected. Might you have misspelled it later on in the code or forgot the `$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to paste the exact array for us to see whats going on. i tried using your above code snippet it works.
Your $big_array will be like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [in] => #pp1
            [ot] => the-r1
            [fn] => the_r1()
            [js] => $('the-r1').val($('#pp1').val());
            [ep] => not tested
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [in] => #pp1
            [ot] => the-r1
            [fn] => the_r1()
            [js] => $('the-r1').val($('#pp1').val());
            [ep] => not tested
        )

)

so its multidimensional to loop through it with foreach you need to do the following.
foreach($big_array as $k=>$v) {
foreach($v as $v1) {
echo $v1."<br>";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct

```
print_r($big_array);

if(is_array($big_array)) echo 'is array'; else echo 'not array';
```

will output "is array"